# I am having an issue with this android studio Kotlin program:

Tags: android, kotlin

I am running an app that has 2 buttons, one for increasing value and another for decreasing value. In this, I need to run the values between 10 and 0 but I couldn't do it(whenever I run the app, it goes below 0 and over 10).

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
var count = 10
        val textCount = findViewById<View>(R.id.textView) as TextView
        val buttonred = findViewById<View>(R.id.injury) as Button
        val buttoning = findViewById<View>(R.id.vial) as Button
         if (count >= 0) {
            println(count)
            buttonred.setOnClickListener {
                count--
                textCount.text = count.toString()

            }
            if (count <= 10)
            {buttoning.setOnClickListener {
                count += 3
                textCount.text = count.toString()
            }}
 }
}
```

XML

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="145dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="145dp"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/injury"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="150dp"
        android:text="injury"
         />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/vial"
        android:layout_width="197dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="109dp"
        android:text="vial" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I need help to clear this.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? its not clear at all from the description ;D

Comment: Just for your information, In Kotlin, You don't to bind views like java. Just give them an ID then call them in the code.

Comment: you put the logic in wrong way, you need to check the count value inside setOnClickListener, for example: `buttonred.setOnClickListener { if (count >= 0) {count -- }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how if you move `if statement` inside the listener

```
        buttonred.setOnClickListener {
            if(count >= 0){
                count--
                textCount.text = count.toString()
            }
        }
        buttoning.setOnClickListener {
            if(count <= 10){
                count += 3
                textCount.text = count.toString()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your logic is wrong.

The most primary thing to understand is the **IF** condition

### `count <= 10 && count >= 0`

In Basic English this means: count can only be less than and equal to 10 **AND** greater than and equal to 0. This would make sure that both `buttonRed` and `buttonIng` will not surpass values 0 to 10 when they are clicked.

```
buttonRed.setOnClickListener {
    if (count >= 0 && count <= 10) {
        count++ 
        textCount.text = count.toString()   
    }
}

buttonIng.setOnClickListener {
    if (count <= 10 && count >= 0) {
        count--
    textCount.text = count.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "=" i.e

if (count > 0) {
println(count)
buttonred.setOnClickListener {
count--
textCount.text = count.toString()

```
        }
        if (count < 10)
        {buttoning.setOnClickListener {
            count += 3
            textCount.text = count.toString()
        }}
```